# React element object unique key still generates error 'Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created an object of react element objects like this:

```
    headHTML.map((el, index) => {
      // console.log(el)
      if (el !== "\n") {
        if (typeof el === 'object' && el !== null) {
          fullHead.push(createElement(el.type, { key: (index / 2 + 1).toString() + 'uniquee', ...el.props }))
        }
      }
      return null
    })
```

When consol.logged it shows like this: (the keys are definitely unique)

```
0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'title', key: '1uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'meta', key: '2uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'meta', key: '3uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
3: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'link', key: '4uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
4: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'meta', key: '5uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
5: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'meta', key: '6uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
6: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'meta', key: '7uniquee', ref: null, props: {…}, …}
```

But when rendered here:

```
<Head>
{fullHead.map((el, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      {el}
    </>
  )
}) ?? ""}
</Head>
```

It still gives an error:

> client.js:1  Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

In the meantime I found a partial solution, that solves this error, but generates another.

I turns out it's possible to assign a key to a React Fragment, we just need to use the full syntax:

```
<Head>
{fullHead.map((el, index) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={index + "uniqueee"}>
      {el} // this gives the typescript error 2322, should I say: 'el as ReactNode'?
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}) ?? ""}
</Head>
```

This has solved my problem, yet I still don't understand why the error was showing and I am getting another error now:

> Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)

Comment: But can you use the Head component? https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head

Comment: I am using <Head> from nextjs, just added it to the code samples.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with your code. By itself, it seems to render correctly and apply the keys when I embed it inside a basic `<App>{fullHead}</App>`. Are there perhaps more elements in `fullHead` that do not have keys? Either that, or you're wrapping it somehow in something that doesn't have keys, or even more likely, you've minified your output into a single line so that there is only one line of code and you don't have any source maps linked. One other possibility I can think of is you're generating these outside of the component render cycle somehow, so that `key` gets stripped.

Comment: There are other elements in fullHead, they all follow the same structure and have keys. Source maps are linked correctly in dev environment. Indeed everything renders correctly, but I want to understand those errors. All logic is within a NextPage component, no abstractions.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread your original post. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your original solution doesn't work, and that the React.Fragment approach does, is because React treats a fragment as a component just like any other, only that it does not render it in the DOM.

In React, the key prop is used to uniquely identify elements in a list because that's how it keeps track of each item's identity – all so that it can efficiently update and re-render the list. Without a key, React would have to re-render the entire list every time something changes. (You can read more about the `key` prop here: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop).

Ultimately the reason that your key solution by adding elements to `fullHead` didn't work, is because by wrapping a component in a fragment, React is now going to look at the fragment for a key, not the component(s) inside of it.

Ergo, this won't work:

```
<Head>
{fullHead.map((el, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      {el}
    </>
  )
}) ?? ""}
</Head>
```

But you discovered that this will (note that `<>` and `<React.Fragment>` are the same thing, only that the shorthand `<>` can't take props).

```
{fullHead.map((el, index) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={index + "uniqueee"}>
      {el}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}) ?? ""}
```

You can certainly keep it this way, which is much more readable, but if for some reason you really needed to keep doing things with the builder function, you can use the component instance directly:

```
const fullHead: any = [];
[
  { props: { "data-name": "apple" }, type: "object" },
  { props: { "data-name": "pear" }, type: "object" },
  "\n",
].map((el, index) => {
  // console.log(el)
  if (el !== "\n") {
    if (typeof el === "object" && el !== null) {
      fullHead.push(
        createElement(el.type, { key: (index / 2 + 1).toString() + "uniquee", ...el.props })
      );
    }
  }
  return null;
});

export const Layout = () => (
  <Head>
    {fullHead}
    {/* ^ this is an instance of your header elements, 
        not an array of components to render */}

  </Head>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea to render the whole array immediately without mapping over it works, but gives me an error: 

Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactFragment'.

Should I say {fullHeas as ReactNode} Do you maybe understand those two types? ReactNode, and ReactFragment types?

Comment: `const fullHead: React.ReactNode[] = [];`